# Game server in Unity3D by Node.JS

Tags: node.js, database, unity-game-engine, server, socket.io

I want to program my back-end side of my game by Node.js.

Back-end stuffs of my game are 1) Login and Registration 2) Profile 3) Sending message to other users and Inbox 4) Sending Notification 5) Set some information i.e. store information or any other things

Now I want to know Node.JS is suitable or not ? I've watched some tutorials about Node.js before.

I know a little about Socket.io too. So I think by myself combining Node.js and Socket.io is good in Unity3D.

The second question is which data base should I use ?

Comment: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/anyone-using-node-js-as-server.121571/

Comment: I've read that topic before, They talk about agreement or disagreement of using Node.js as a game server. I want to know more is it suitable for these kind of tasks or not. And some beginners guide to start if it's good.

Comment: What do you think about Pomelo ? : http://pomelo.netease.com/index.html

Answer (score 5):

It's posible i did create a game server with nodejs and Heroku host free.

First i use socket.io (or WS) to communicate between Server and Client.

- Unity Socket.io: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721
- WS npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws
- Heroku: https://dashboard.heroku.com/
- MongoDB: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab

Second i send token to verify account and use MongoDB to save data.

- Github source: https://github.com/co-chi-tam/WarriorRoad3D

Some screenshot:

[image]

It work like a charm :D

Comment: Oh, Nice, Many thanks. Just I want to know do you have any tutorial or topic that explain Node.js in details ? I will check your project and of course learn many things.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com//nodejs/nodejs_introduction.htm Simple way

Answer (score 1):

Use firebase. Here are a few tutorials that may help you get started quickly.

- [Using Firebase in Unity3D Tutorial 1: Basics and setup](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/using-firebase-in-unity3d-tutorial-i-basics-and-setup/)
- [Using Firebase in Unity3D Tutorial 2: Authorization and User Login with email and password](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2017/01/22/using-firebase-in-unity3d-tutorial-2-authorization-and-user-login-example-with-user-name-and-password/)

Comment: Does it support all of my needs ? I'm not sure it is, for example does it support chat in the game ? If I want to use Node.js, Is it suitable ? or it makes my game destroy ? Actually I want to know that some beginner tips for implement these tasks by Node.js.

Comment: Is it possible to use Firebase for chatting in the game ? Do you have any tutorial for it ?

Comment: Just for clarification, for login and registration I must use "Authentication" feature ? for retrieve data of user profile I must use "Realtime Database" ? For sending message to our friends or any other users which feature I must use ? For notification I must use "Cloud Messaging" feature ? For retrieve data for example for sale information I must use "Remote Config" ? And for a last one I want to know how I can check code invitation for giving reward ?

Comment: @ATHellboy I think all your questions are properly answered in Firebase documentation. You need dig into it.